# c# decode encodeURIComponent with åäö characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I use an AJAX-POST function that sends a json-object based on my model(MVC, razor). `Model.parameterValue` contains åäö characters, i have problem to decode these.

This is my post:

```
                    var jsondataobject = {partner: encodeURIComponent('@Model.parameterValue')};
                    var stringobject = JSON.stringify(jsondataobject);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        url: JSurl + "/Admin/SaveNewTemplate",
                        data: "jsonData=" + stringobject,
                        success: function (returnPayload) {
                            console && console.log("request succeeded");
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            console && console.log("request failed");
                        },

                        processData: false,
                        async: false
                    });
```

In my controller i use the following code to get my values

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, string> sData = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonData);
string _partner = sData["partner"].ToString();
```

when my model has the value `"Testforetagö"`, _partner gets the value `"Testforetag&#246;"`. If i try to decode the partner value with:

```
string _partner = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(sData["partner"].ToString());
```

I still get `"Testforetag&#246;"`

Any suggestion on how i could solve this?